# Module pattern instantiated in a window property

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I need to code a module pattern instantiated in a window property. What would be the best way of doing that?

```
var widget = (function(){


}());
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Can you give more details? The code you've quoted is correct as far as it goes. What you do next depends a lot on what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Every variable you declare in your everyday browser should be accessible through `window`. E.g. `var foo = 3; window["foo"] // returns 3`

Comment: it is a question in a test. "Create a module pattern instantiated in a window  property".

Answer (score 0):

The new best practice in JS world is to use [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) or [es6 modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) with [rollup](http://rollupjs.org/) library and/or [babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Short answer to your question

```
(function(global){
    global.widgetName = {};
}(this));
```